# Cumulative Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose the % of an independent event happening is 20%. If I want to compute the probability of the independent event occurring at least 1 or more times if the event happens two times, would I be correct with the following math:

```
100 - ((100 - 20%) * (100-20%) / 100)
```

To illustrate, say you have 5 unique cards, so drawing at random 1 card, the chance of that card being the desired one, is 20%. But if I draw once, put the card back, and draw again, what are the CUMULATIVE odds of getting the desired card at least ONCE in either the first OR second draw.

If my math above is correct, the answer would be "The chance of drawing the desired card at least once over those two draws is 36%. Am I correct in my thinking?

Comment: yep that seems correct

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your formula is, essentially, the [Rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) applied to [Complementary events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event).